# How to update loopback models with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, loopback

I updated the lbservice by the command line

```
lb-ng server/server.js client/js/services/lb-services.js
```

and it deleted me some functions in lb-service.js file, like logout.

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have modified the generated service and launch the command again, your changes have been overwrited. If you have not saved your changes, they are unfortunatelly lost.

Frop [Loopback docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Create-AngularJS-client.html):

> Generate `lb-services.js`
>
> To generate the Angular services for a LoopBack application, use the
>   AngularJS SDK lb-ng command-line tool.  First, create the
>   client/js/services directory, if you don’t already have it (by using
>   the mkdir command, for example), then in the project root directory,
>   enter the lb-ng command as follows:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir -p client/js/services
> $ lb-ng server/server.js client/js/services/lb-services.js
> ```
>
> This command creates `client/js/services/lb-services.js`.

Comment: yes i know this. but when i first create the lb-services file, he automatic create me those functions. but now, it seems a completely different file.